# fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the ListObjects operation: Forbidden | Resuming an aws s3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cli

So I have a storreduce appliance and was running a sync job which died half-way through

```
aws s3 sync /jobs/ads/ --endpoint-url=http://data:5080 s3://chicago-stagin
```

The problem now is that I can't resume the job or resubmit the sync, I get the following running the above command

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the ListObjects operation: Forbidden
```

I can cp a file up to the bucket no problem

```
aws s3 cp /var/log/messages --endpoint-url=http://data:5080 s3://chicago-staging
upload: ./messages to s3://chicago-staging/messages
```

There are no security policies on the bucket and I can read files too;

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url=http://data.chi.themill.com:5080 s3://chicago-staging
                       PRE .ARCHIVE/
                       PRE .common/
```

Any ideas?

*UPDATE:

Fixed by adding this into ~/.aws/config

```
[default]
 s3 =
 signature_version = s3
```

Comment: Idea: use `--debug` to find the actual error.

Comment: Ummm... also, your working examples use an apparently different `--endpoint-url` **and** a different bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

if you added the permissions already and still not working you must run the following command in your terminal

```
aws configure
```

it will ask you for id and secret you can skip the other question once done it should work fine

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have given ListBucket permission to the chicago-staging bucket itself.

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
    "Sid": "<id>",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::chicago-staging",
        "arn:aws:s3:::chicago-staging/*"
    ]
 }
] 
}
```